# Network error on calling API with React Native and expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo `42.0.1` version and I am receiving the following error on a POST request. The API that I am using is `https://api.x.x/`. This is not actually a new issue, I had faced it sometime before but it went away as it came. I am curious what is causing this and what solution would be appropriate?

```
"Error: Network Error
    at createError (http://192.168.1.68:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:159833:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://192.168.1.68:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:159737:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (http://192.168.1.68:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:32800:27)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://192.168.1.68:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:31965:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (http://192.168.1.68:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:31781:16)
    at http://192.168.1.68:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:31891:47
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (http://192.168.1.68:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:4018:37)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://192.168.1.68:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:3204:31)
    at http://192.168.1.68:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:2936:17
    at MessageQueue.__guard (http://192.168.1.68:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:3158:13)"
```

And on error I am also, receiving `isAxiosError: true`, may be it could be related to axios and expo?

Comment: Check your current ip in env file/backend url corresponds with your backend ip. If not update, clear cache, and restart.

Comment: @Arcanus It is the same. In my .env I have `https://api.placeholder.com/v1` and the error response on my debugger shows the base url is the same.

Comment: Hey were you able to solve this problem, I'm facing the same issue nad have no idea how to fix it.